# Unknown proj4: how to create custom proj4 from wkt?

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text, sf, sp

I have a shapefile with a .prj file I've never seen before. In fact, it seems that GDAL doesn't even know what it is (see below).

Therefore, when I read it into R with `raster::shapefile()` the CRS isn't set. When I set it to the closest thing I can find ([ESRI:54030](https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54030/), or [ESRI:53030](https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/53030/)), the projection is still off (even when I modify the Central Meridian with "+lon_0=11" in the proj4string).

Here's the WKT:

```
(base) Richs-MacBook-Pro:whymapdata_world richpauloo$ gdalsrsinfo wrb11hyg_7d84d.prj

ERROR 6: No translation for Robinson_ARC_INFO to PROJ.4 format is known.
PROJ.4 : 

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Robinson_ARC_INFO",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Robinson_ARC_INFO"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",11.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

If I compare this to the WTK for ESRI:54030 and ESRI:53030 they're clearly not the same.

What projection do I have? How can I set the projection for this object in R for either an sp or sf object? Do I need to write a custom proj4 string from this WKT?

Comment: Not in R but a possible workaround: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8547/what-is-the-best-way-to-programmatically-convert-between-wkt-and-proj4-string

Comment: I can only find a few mentions of the Robinson_ARC_INFO projection - see comment from mkennedy on this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160563/explaining-gap-between-robinson-wgs84-epsg-54030-in-qgis-and-arcmap - sounds old and nonstandard. I think you'll need to define your own CRS/manually apply the parameters in the WKT to proj syntax - I think you'd need st_set_crs combined with the proj string built from the WKT - that said, it might be missing some parameters, so I'm unclear if it will be precise or just get the data close